# Service account permissions to create email group

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create email groups using Service Accounts. Lost in the documentation what IAM permissions are required to do it. What are the minimum permissions to be added to achieve this task?
For reference, i am using the directory API

```
discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: Which **groups** are you using. Google Groups or Google Workspace? For the first, there is no IAM role that you can grant. For the second, you must use a domain wide delegated service account.

Comment: I think I am using the Google workspace. Just trying to create Email Groups, not sure which one it falls into

Answer (score 0):

You need to add role in Google workspace.

To create group you need **Groups Admin**

[image]

Comment: Thats right, but that would require some user to give the access. How can i do the same for service accounts so that these things can be automated